What does it mean when a person says they can't sing in that key, that the key is too high or too low?
We have a local music club where we play instruments and sing songs together. Often someone will say, "I can't sing that song in that key." People will say I can't sing in that key because it's too low or too high. Often the the songs are in the keys of C, or D or G. I don't understand this and I'm not formally trained or educated in music or music theory. Isn't the Key of C, C? But there are lower or higher octaves of the note C.
Doesn't a choir or choral group with sopranos, tenors, baritones and basses sing the same song in the same key but at different octaves?
Help!

It's not really a duplicate, but the answers to this question might help explain it.

Short version: Yeah, most people have the note "C," in some octave, within their vocal range. But most songs have more than one note. The "Star Spangled Banner" goes from one C up past the next one and tops out at the next G, a distance of 1.5 octaves. Look at the range chart in Michael's answer on the linked question: That fits neatly inside the soprano range, but the alto, if their lowest note is middle C, can't reach the top G (or, if they choose one octave lower, can't go down to the low C).

For an example, start singing a simple song, eg. happy birthday, but start fairly high in your range. You'll soon find that at some point you can't hit that high note near the end at all (or it will sound very humorous!). A singer will quickly be able to recognise this, without needing to vocalise, and say 'no this key is too high/low (read, it stretches my range too high/low). They are not saying the key of C is too high, they are saying this song IN the key of C is too high for me. For some other song with a narrow range they may be able to sing it in C, or potentially any key, just fine.

The question may be unclear or misunderstood: it asks simply about singing in a particular key — but the given example is about singing a specific song in a particular key.  (The former doesn't make much sense in general, while the latter does.)

Here’s a concrete example. The song “Wind beneath My Wings” has a range of an octave and a fourth — 11 white keys on a piano.
When sung in the key of C, the range is from G to C (indicated in red, below). When sung in D, the range is from A to D (indicated in blue, below).
For Singer 1, G might be a bit too low, but A is okay. For Singer 2, the upper D might be a bit too high, but C is fine. So Singer 1 will want the song in D (from notes A to D), while Singer 2 will prefer C (from notes G to C). Singer 3, though, has a wider vocal range, so can perform the song in either C or D. In fact, Singer 3 could sing the song in Bb, B, C, Db, D, Eb, E, or F. In Singer 3's case, the choice of key could be where their voice feels most comfortable or perhaps the key that's easiest for the accompanist(s).

Choirs operate a bit differently. In larger groups, there will be multiple people singing the same part, which can compensate if someone in a section can't comfortably sing a particular note. Smaller groups, where individual singers are more exposed, only select people whose vocal range is sufficient for that group's repertoire.

Songs in, say, key C, don't necessarily have a range of C to a C an octave higher. There are also songs which have a greater range than one octave, often one and a half octaves. Few songs will have a range of much more than that, after all, when writing a song, it needs to be singable by lots of folk, surely! That means that the range of those songs needs to match the range of a person's voice.
So, saying  'I can't sing in that particular key' means that their range doesn't suit that particular key. It may be too high, or too low, considering the highest or lowest notes needed to be sung. Most people will have a range of at least an octave, I guess one and a half might be the lower end. Some have a range of way more than that. Karen Carpenter's was 4 octaves, so she could have sung pretty well any song, in any key. but that's exceptional.
Often, just moving a song up (or down) by a tone or so, will bring most songs into a comfortable singing range for most. The problem is, in doing that, it will help one singer, but maybe take another, singing harmony, out of their range. A problem I've encountered scores of times with harmony singing.

Adding to the answer by @Tim in addition to songs that have a range exceeding C to C, quite a lot of songs have a range split around C.  C is the "middle note" and there are higher and lower notes.  Happy Birthday is a good example of this: in the key of C it uses the notes G A B C D E F G.  People often sing this in the key of F specifically so that the range of the song extends C to C, where a majority of people can sing comfortably.

Great answers all around!
I'll add two things, as a long time band leader and musician;

On some occasions, a singer will be technically able to hit the notes in a given key, but just feel that their voice will sound more pleasing in a slightly lower or higher key. (or that singing in the original key will be a strain on their voice, especially so early in the set)
My girl singer was famous for just such requests.

It's subjective, yes, but musicians sometimes need to adjust and transpose into a different key to make their diva happy.

A lot of singers will find that, as they get older, they are no longer able to hit the high notes anymore. (Think, for example, Steve Perry of Journey and Jon Bon Jovi of Bon Jovi fame.) That original key just isn't going to work.

I myself used to be able to sing the classic The Lion Sleeps tonight in the original key of F, with the chords played being F, Bb, C. As the years wore on, I find that if we perform that crowd-pleasing song, we have to perform it in E, A, B.   And even that is on the edge of straining our voices.
